# Toggling a div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like for the div `#share-sub-bottom` to be toggled between shown and hidden when the user clicks the add photo link. For some reason, I cannot get it to work, what could I be doing wrong?

Jsfiddle Demo
http://jsfiddle.net/Jzp5H/1/

Comment: Here's a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/Jzp5H/12/

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jzp5H/2/) . You gave to `Add photo` link the class `class=".show_hide"` and this is not correct. You should gave it `show_hide`

Answer (score 1):

remove the dot from your class definition, and it works like charm

this you have

`<p> <a href="#" class=".show_hide"> Add Photo </a> </p>`

this you should have

`<p> <a href="#" class="show_hide"> Add Photo </a> </p>`

Answer (score 1):

Hi now demo  http://jsfiddle.net/Jzp5H/8/

```
<a href="#" class=".show_hide"> Add Photo </a>
```

**into this**

```
<a href="#" class="show_hide"> Add Photo </a>
```

**Do not use a dot in front** `class=".show_hide"` used simply `class="show_hide"`

Answer (score 1):

Change in your html file for this line:

```
<a href="#" class=".show_hide"> Add Photo </a>
```

To this:

```
<a href="#" class="show_hide"> Add Photo </a>
```

Don't use dot(.) in front.